# Pi Jessie & VNC

Tags: vnc

I recently updated my Raspberry Pi to Raspian Jessie. I've installed VNC Server and was able to connect remotely to the Pi using my Google Pixel phone and the VNC Viewer app.

I cannot connect using either of my two laptops. When i try it says "Timed out waiting for a response from the computer"

I know it works because i can get in using the same IP address on my phone but not on my computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: You never mentioned what you installed on the pi or what you're using in your laptop's to try to connect

Comment: I've tried installing tightvncserver and using the vncserver that comes pre-packaged. I'm trying to use vnc viewer on my laptop to connect

Comment: If you're using real vnc on the pi, you have to use real vnc viewer to connect to it. You've still not been very clear about the programs you're using

Comment: Okay so i used sudo apt install -y realvnc-vnc-server and then vncserver which showed "New desktop is raspberrypi:2" and the IP address. When i tried VNC Viewer on the PC it said "Timed out waiting for response from the computer". If i use tightvncviewer it comes up with "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: Just a quick update. I've changed to wheezy and having the same problem! It's on both laptops; it must be a router issue right?